# Can I get animation from Reality Composer by coding?

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

I got a usdz model with animation by reality converter, then imported it into my realitykit project. In reality composer, I can set a trigger, for example, click the model to play the animation. But I still can't find a way to control animation in Swift code.

When I print entity.availableAnimations[0].definition, it outputs an empty object. So how can I get the animation? Thank you very much.

```
print(cat!.availableAnimations[0].definition) outputs:
```

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

Check and verify if the animation is correctly exported in the USDZ file: You can use Quick Look or Xcode's Preview to check if the animations are properly included in the USDZ file. Open the USDZ file in Finder, then press the spacebar to preview the file using Quick Look. Alternatively, you can drag the USDZ file into an empty Xcode project and use the built-in preview feature to test the animation.

and to control the animation of a USDZ model in RealityKit using code.

```
import UIKit
import RealityKit
import Combine

    class ViewController: UIViewController {
        
        @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
        var modelEntity: ModelEntity?
        var animationController: AnimationPlaybackController?
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            
            let modelAnchor = try! Experience.loadModel()
            arView.scene.anchors.append(modelAnchor)
            
            if let modelEntity = modelAnchor.findEntity(named: "YourModelName") as? ModelEntity {
                self.modelEntity = modelEntity
                if let animationResource = modelEntity.availableAnimations.first {
                    animationController = modelEntity.playAnimation(animationResource,
                                                                    transitionDuration: 0.5,
                                                                    blendLayerOffset: 0,
                                                                    repeatMode: .repeat(1),
                                                                    delay: 0)
                }
            }
        }
        
        // A function to play the animation when you want to trigger it.
        func playAnimation() {
            guard let animationController = animationController else { return }
            animationController.resume()
        }
        
        // A function to pause the animation.
        func pauseAnimation() {
            guard let animationController = animationController else { return }
            animationController.pause()
        }
    }
```